# Differences between two ODE solvers

Tags: python, solver, odeint

I am wondering, what are the differences between `ODEINT` and `solve_ivp` for solving a differential equation. What could be advantages and disadvantages between them?

```
f1 = solve_ivp(f, [0,1], y0) #y0 is the initial point
f2 = odeint(f, y0, [0, 1], args=(a, b)) # a and b are arguments of function f
```

Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well the main difference is the following:

1. `odeint` came first and is uses **lsoda** from the FORTRAN package [odepack](https://computation.llnl.gov/casc/odepack/) to solve ODEs.
2. `solve_ivp` is a more general solution that lets use decide which integrator to use to solve ODEs. If you define the `method` param as `method='LSODA'` then this will use the same integrator as `odeint`. Additionally you can choose other methods such as **BDF** and **RK25**.

Regarding performance, there is a ticket that indicate that `solve_ivp` is slower. This maybe because its written in Python.

> https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/8257

Check the docs for both of them in scipy:

> https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.2.1/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html
>   https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.2.1/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html

Comment: So, `solve_ivp` is better to solve the ODEs, but is slower than `ODEINT`.

Comment: Read this: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/8257#issuecomment-359182872. I suppose not noticeable for most problems.

Comment: I am getting similar performance differences.  `solve_ivp` with `method='LSODA'` takes 1.11s.  `odeint` takes 0.21s.  Maximum difference between solutions is about `5e-06`